# Insert into a table in another database after first deleting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two databases that have same tables on those. First I had to delete all the data in `employee_table` in `Database_1`. Then after that I need to insert data in the `employee_table` in `Database_2` to the `employee_table` in the `Database_1`.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2017.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: what have you try? you should ask question instead of letting us do your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first insert data to database_2 and then delete from database 1 with this command:

```
INSERT INTO [Database_2].dbo.emplyee_table
SELECT * From [Database_1].dbo.employee_table

DELETE FROM [Database_1].dbo.employee_table
```